# DIVIDE FUNCTION FOR GRATER THAN VALUE

Tags: excel-formula

If the total sum value is 100, I want to divide by 5 to all sum values of 10 and above. What will be a formula in excel for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Office365 you could use the following:

```
=LET(sumrange,A1:A9,
     summed,SUM(sumrange), 
     alteredsum,SUM(IF(sumrange>10,sumrange/5,sumrange)),
IF(summed=100,alteredsum,summed))
```

Else (`ctrl+shift+enter` required):

```
=IF(SUM(A1:A9)=100,
    SUM(IF(A1:A9>10,A1:A9/5,A1:A9)),
    SUM(A1:A9))
```

*Change the range to your needs.